# Speeding up array lookup after traversing?

Tags: c#, performance, gpu, lookup

I have a 123MB big `int`array, and it is basically used like this:

```
private static int[] data = new int[32487834]; 
static int eval(int[] c)
{
    int p = data[c[0]];
    p = data[p + c[1]];
    p = data[p + c[2]];
    p = data[p + c[3]];
    p = data[p + c[4]];
    p = data[p + c[5]];
    return data[p + c[6]];
}
```

`eval()` is called a lot (~50B times) with different `c` and I would like to know if (and how) I could speed it up.

I already use a [unsafe function with an fixed array](https://gist.github.com/4387720) that makes use of all the CPUs. It's a C# port of the [TwoPlusTwo 7 card evaluator by RayW](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/poker-hand-evaluator-roundup#2p2). The C++ version is insignificantly faster.

Can the GPU be used to speed this up?

Comment: I wasn't sure how my question could be as useful as possible for others, therefore I generalized the function and added my current implementation as gist-snippet. If thats wrong, feel free to edit my question.

Comment: one way would be to parallelize this function across multiple cores...

Comment: [I already do](https://gist.github.com/4387720)

Comment: Maybe caching your array reference in a variable would help - var current = Hands[i]; But I doubt it'd make any difference....

Comment: What do you mean by `insignificantly faster` ?

Comment: HOW fast do you NEED it? I am not a Poker guy, but as I understand you need this algo to determine the winning odds for a given set of "cards"? If that is true, you dont need to check ALL possible combinations, but only some 100k. After that you will get a percentage value that is already "good", like 42 (% chance to win). Maybe this would (after 10M additional iterations) change to 41.4 or 42.6, but would that make a DIFFERENCE?

Comment: @leppie: I don't have a working multicore version of random hands for the TwoPlusTwo Evaluator, but my C# solution takes about 160ms to enumerate all 133M hands, the c++ I found needs 327ms.. I'm more interested in random evaluations and I'm not proficient to customize the one I have.

Comment: @igrimpe, it's true that for example AsKd vs QdQh a few thousand evaluations are enough, but if you want range vs range, you need a huge number of evaluations. Do this many times, it can't be fast enough.

Comment: Do you know in advance what are the contents of the array? And/or can you somehow predict the value of p? Depending on its value your code can be incredibly inefficient as you may not be taking profit of the processor's cache

Comment: You could also remove the calls to that method as you are paying 50B times that overhead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Cache the array reference into a local variable. Static field accesses are generally slower than locals for multiple reasons (one of them is that the field can change so it has to be reloaded all the time. The JIT can optimize locals much more freely).
2. Don't use an array as the argument to the method. Hard-code 7 integer-indices. That reduces array allocation, indirection-penalty and bounds checking.
3. Use unsafe code to index into the array. This will eliminate bounds checking. Use a `GCHandle` to fix the array and cache the pointer in a static field (don't just use a fixed-block - I believe it has certain (small) overhead associated with entering it. Not sure).
4. As an alternative to fixing the array, allocate the 123MB array using `VirtualAlloc` and use huge pages. That cuts down on TLB misses.

All of these are hardcore low-level optimizations. They only apply if you need maximum performance.

I think we are pretty much at the limit here when it comes to optimizing this function. We probably can only do better if you show the caller of the function so that they can be optimized as a single unit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. *I know some of those words*, more research for me ;)

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/4389176) is the current initialization, suggestions? I don't know if thats the right place here..

Comment: That looks fine. You can now change the `HR` array to an `int*` that points to a buffer allocated with `VirtualAlloc` passing `MEM_LARGE_PAGES`. You need to `memcpy` to that buffer and use that buffer in your calculation.

Comment: Well, again [I know some of those words](http://i.imgur.com/2W5ZA.jpg). I'm sorry, but Google did absolutely not help. You probably wanted me to use P/Invoke with those C++ functions, but I couldn't find a single relevant example. Should I ask a new question in regards to this or can you help me with that?

Comment: @BeatMe I understand. If the docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) don't help you (I think they're good) I suggest you ask "How does allocating and using native memory with VirtualAlloc work with C#?". I think you'll get a more holistic answer from that than I can provide in a few lines. If you mention that you are not proficient with unsafe code yet you'll probably get very actionable answers. Feel free to post the link to the question here, though.