# How can I allocate and use native memory with VirtualAlloc with C#?

Tags: c#, performance, pinvoke

In order to maximize performance of a critical method, [in another question it was suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054557/speeding-up-array-lookup-after-traversing) that I allocate and use the memory of the array natively instead of fixing it.

I'm working in C# and have no experience with unsafe code and using P/invoke. I haven't found any relevant examples on Google and the [MSDN article about VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) didn't help either.

This is a method which is called Billion of times and every bit of performance is desirable.

```
    public static readonly int[] HR = new int[32487834];
    public unsafe int eval(int c1, int c2, int c3, int c4, int c5, int c6, int c7)
    {
        fixed (int* HR = Evaluator.HR)
        {
            int p = HR[53 + c1];
            p = HR[p + c2];
            p = HR[p + c3];
            p = HR[p + c4];
            p = HR[p + c5];
            p = HR[p + c6];
            return (HR[p + c7]);
        }
    }
```

If you're interested, it's a C# port of the [TwoPlusTwo-Evaluator](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/poker-hand-evaluator-roundup#2p2) which uses a 123mb lookup-table to return the rank of a random 7-card-pokerhand for comparison. I average about 80M evaluations/s in random order and 500M evaluations/s in consecutive order (c1=0, c2=1, loops incrementing every variable up to 52) on my machine.

Comment: What do you mean by "work"?

Comment: @annoying_squid sorry, I changed the question title according to my intention. I do not want how it *works*, but how I can do it.

Comment: How fast is this code already? Have you benchmarked?

Comment: If you are familiar with c++/CLI I found that to be handy for writing native code in.  Just wrap it in a function and compile it as an assembly.  Also remember that any native variables are not garbage collected by default.

Comment: @annoying_squid No, thats the reason I got that much problems.

Comment: @MitchWheat about 500M/s in consecutive order (c1=1, c2=2.. with incrementing values) and 80M/s in random order on my machine. It's the fastest evaluator known, but it may be called Billion of times and the slightest optimization can speed it up a lot.

Comment: Can this method be implemented inline? If it's going to be called that often, the last thing you need is the overhead of method calls.

Comment: Well, difficult as the situations constantly change. I might do several different methods that can react to that, but the lookup is always the same. Probably a question for another day, this here is only about native VirtualAlloc in C# ;)

Comment: This is a pretty pointless exercise.  You assume it has something to do with the language, the real problem is that you are not using the processor's L1 cache effectively.  The problem-set just doesn't fit, the array is too large and the access pattern is too random.  You'll need better hardware to get ahead, like a Xeon processor.

Comment: @HansPassant If you have a better idea for solving the problem of getting a rank out of 7/52 cards, go ahead. Precomputing is the fastest method known and this 123MB table is one of the smallest availabe. I have a another 2-step lookup with smaller arrays which is half as fast but speed is everything in that domain. You may be right that it's a pointless exercise though, but that is only partial relevant to my question.

Comment: The bottom line is: it is already very fast, and it's practical application is what, poker!

Comment: You should first of all work out what your real problem is instead of making guesses.

Comment: For clarification, I think Hans meant L2/L3 caches.  Only the E74xx series Xeon chips has a larger-than-normal L1 cache, and Intel hasn't bothered to duplicate that experiment since due to low real-world performance benefit vs. much higher cost.  And fwiw, I doubt even the enlarged L2/L3 caches of such chips would help here.  Even when they are effective (typically on datatsets smaller than 32mb only) the improvement is only 10-15% over equivalent desktop designs.  For a 132mb dataset... expect far less of a difference.

Comment: @BeatMe: Offhand I'd suggest trying to find ways to break up the dependency chain.  For example, the algo overall would probably be much faster if you could do the look-up for c1, c2, c3, etc in separate loops of approx 8192 each.  It might seem like more work, since you'll be building additional tables to cache the interm results, but the L1 cache performance improvement should outweigh it by an order of magnitude.  I wouldn't be surprised if such an approach could double the throughput of the random access benchmark -- it may penalize sequential access tho (but only slightly, I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your example is that you must use the `fixed` directive ***from outside*** the looping code.  Using it inside this nested function won't really help and could possibly make things worse since it will make C# internally invoke its GC memory pinning API.  So a much better solution would have code like this:

```
public unsafe int eval(int* HR, int c1, int c2, int c3, int c4, int c5, int c6, int c7)
{
    int p = HR[53 + c1];
    p = HR[p + c2];
    p = HR[p + c3];
    p = HR[p + c4];
    p = HR[p + c5];
    p = HR[p + c6];
    return (HR[p + c7]);
}
```

`fixed` is essentially a language construct synonym for [GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.addrofpinnedobject.aspx).  In your case omitting the bounds checking on eight array fetches out-weighed the cost of pinning and unpinning the memory via the GC every time you entered that function... but probably not by much.

Using P/Invoke is generally not trivial, and I would recommend against it unless you want to spend a few days familiarizing yourself with the territory.  It is even more challenging if you aren't already familiar with Win32/WinAPI programming via C++.  Better to rework your code so that you can pin memory as high up the chain as possible.  For this specific purpose you could even just as well create a GCHandle for that array as part of your object constructor.

Comment: As an addendum, I think this would also have been the appropriate answer to the other question you linked in the OP.  Some people frown on the idea of using GCHandle to lock large swaths of the GC heap for long periods of time, but mostly those fears are unfounded.  The Large Blob heap is rarely compacted anyway, and having some big allocs pinned down won't impact performance of C#'s frequent smaller object allocations at all, since those essentially sort into an entirely separate GC heap altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use C++/Cli:

```
ref class Evaluator
{
public:
  static Int32* HR;
  static Evaluator()
  {
    int size = 32487834;
    HR = (INT*)malloc(size * 4);
  }

  static Int32 Eval(Int32 c1, Int32 c2, Int32 c3, Int32 c4, Int32 c5, Int32 c6, Int32 c7)
  {
      Int32 p = HR[53 + c1];
      p = HR[p + c2];
      p = HR[p + c3];
      p = HR[p + c4];
      p = HR[p + c5];
      p = HR[p + c6];
      return (HR[p + c7]);

  }
};
```

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question? I already have solutions in C++ for the whole evaluator, I mentioned I'm using a C# port after all.

Comment: @MitchWheat In C++ you have to cast it unless you are assigning to `void*`.